# VS2019 - Automaticly generate XML comment for methods and classes when you save the file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-comments

In Visual Studio, you can write `///` to create an XML documentation comment above a C# method or class. The problem is that you have to manually type three slashes, which is too much for some developers at a company I work at. Therefore, someone has to go through all the files and manually add these comments every now and then.

Are there any settings or extensions or something that would allow us to automatically generate XML documentation? Ideally when saving a file?

Comment: Sounds more like a company policy/enforcement issue. I don't think there is a way to automatically extract the comments out of the developer's head.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and apparently GhostDoc can generate these XML comments for you. Unfortunately it is not for free.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).